# Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

New to this stuff and vscode wont let me debug my C++ file. Whenever i hit F5, i get the following error:

`Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-environment-cd"d:\Users\MyName\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\My Projects"". d:\Users\MyName\OneDrive\Documentos\My Projects: No such file or directory`

This is my `launch.json` file. Ive already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363761/unable-to-start-debugging-unexpected-gdb-output-from-command-environment-cd) solution with no results.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Compilar y depurar el archivo activo",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Strawberry\\c\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo"
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: My advice is to never use a space in a path where you put your `c` or `c++` code. The reason is most compilers use the command line and a space character on the command line separates arguments. To get around the issue the path needs to be quoted.

Comment: Another poster on SO said that they had trouble with accents on file names. Maybe your accents in `impresión` and `sangría` are causing problems.